# (python tkinter) pages with class, variable passed to other page, cant use as label : PY_VAR0

Tags: python, class, tkinter, label

I had a problem with passing a variable from one page to the other, its works now, but if I want to use it on a label, it writes PA_VAR0. I read that ".get()" should be used in that case, but it still doesn't work that way. (with .get() it don't even passes the variable). I tried to set a new variable with tk.StringVar() function, but it still didn't work

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class example(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.shared_data = {
            "variable": tk.StringVar()
        }
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (page1, page2):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(page1)

    def get_page(self, page_class):
        return self.frames[page_class]

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="first page")
        label.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="turn page",
                             command=lambda: self.pageturn())
        button1.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

    def pageturn(self):                                     
        self.controller.shared_data["variable"] = 'string i wanna pass'
        print("variable set here: ", self.controller.shared_data["variable"])
        self.controller.show_frame(page2)


class page2(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        label = ttk.Label(self, text=self.controller.shared_data["variable"])
        label.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text=self.controller.shared_data["variable"].get())
        label.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)
        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text=self.controller.shared_data["variable"],
                             command=lambda: print(self.controller.shared_data["variable"]))
        button3.grid(row=8, column=10, padx=10, pady=10)
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="if fuction sees variable",
                             command=lambda: self.ifok())
        button2.grid(row=9, column=10, padx=10, pady=10)

    def ifok(self):
        if self.controller.shared_data["variable"] == 'string i wanna pass':
            print("ok")


app = example()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwrite `self.controller.shared_data["variable"]` by a string inside `pageturn()`:

```py
self.controller.shared_data["variable"] = 'string i wanna pass'
```

You should use `.set()` instead:

```py
self.controller.shared_data["variable"].set('string i wanna pass')
```

Full updated code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class example(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.shared_data = {
            "variable": tk.StringVar()
        }
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (page1, page2):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(page1)

    def get_page(self, page_class):
        return self.frames[page_class]

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="first page")
        label.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="turn page",
                             command=lambda: self.pageturn())
        button1.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

    def pageturn(self):                                     
        self.controller.shared_data["variable"].set('string i wanna pass') ### changed = to .set()
        print("variable set here: ", self.controller.shared_data["variable"].get()) ### called .get()
        self.controller.show_frame(page2)


class page2(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        label = ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["variable"]) ### changed text to textvariable
        label.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text=self.controller.shared_data["variable"].get())
        label.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)
        button3 = ttk.Button(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["variable"],  ### changed text to textvariable
                             command=lambda: print(self.controller.shared_data["variable"].get()))
        button3.grid(row=8, column=10, padx=10, pady=10)
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="if fuction sees variable",
                             command=lambda: self.ifok())
        button2.grid(row=9, column=10, padx=10, pady=10)

    def ifok(self):
        if self.controller.shared_data["variable"].get() == 'string i wanna pass':  ### called .get()
            print("ok")


app = example()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you, very much! but if it got overwrite, why did it work besides using it az a label?